# passing Entire ArrayList<String> from one activity to other in android

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist

I want to pass a ArrayList from one activity to other.
I have found this link for [pass arraylist from one activity to other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780835/pass-arraylist-from-one-activity-to-other) useful.

But when I am using

```
    ArrayList<String> hyperlinks = new ArrayList<String>();
                           ...

    Intent myIntent=new Intent(Player.this,VideoActivity.class);
                    Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();  
                    mBundle.putStringArrayListExtra("hyperlinks", hyperlinks);
                    //mBundle.putString("filePath", hyperlinks.get(0));  
                    myIntent.putExtras(mBundle); 
                    Player.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Then I am getting error at  **mBundle.putStringArrayListExtra**   ,
Saying that   **The method putStringArrayListExtra(String, ArrayList) is undefined for the type Bundle**

Please guide me how to do this??

Thanks

Comment: please read the Bundle and Intent doc

Comment: it has been answered before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029969/problems-with-putstringarraylistextra-in-android

Comment: [**Please See this Blog. This Can Help You**](http://startandroiddevelopment.blogspot.in/2013/11/how-to-pass-boolean-int-string-integer.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's lots of ways to do it, but have you tried:

```
myIntent.putStringArrayListExtra(key, hyperlinks);
```

Also, the Bundle object has

```
 putStringArrayList
```

Answer (score 2):

check into Application. You can extend your own application, and save the arraylist here

check out ==> [Extending Application to share variables globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572338/extending-application-to-share-variables-globally)

Answer (score 1):

Bundle Documentation clearly indicating that `putStringArrayList(String, ArrayList)` is method of Bundle class, but not `putStringArrayListExtra()`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putStringArrayList(java.lang.String, java.util.ArrayList)

Also, please Check import declarations, and check if **Proper Bundle class** has been imported or not.

Package of Bundle class should be:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
```