# Passing ArrayList<String> from ActivityA to ActivityB

Tags: java, android, android-intent, arraylist

I am making the following app for my school assignment. It is a simple Pizza app, which asks the user to select which topping they would like on their pizza. I ask the user to select the toppings they want by check-boxes. Once the user selects the toppings and clicks the "submit" button, it should open up a new activity and in this new activity it should display what the user had selected from the previous activity.

In other words:

- user checks of -> Onions and Olives
- then user clicks -> Submit
- then new activity opens up, and displays what user selected

Here is my code for first activity called `TanavActivityAd1` and my second activity called `TanavActivityOrder`

**MY CODE: (TanavActivityAd1)(FirstActivity)**

```
package tanav.sharma;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Menu;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TanavActivityAd1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<String> topping = new ArrayList<String>(); // saves what user has checked off
    TextView final_text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tanav_activity_ad1);

        Toolbar my_toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(my_toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.my_tb_tittle);

        //initialize the text view
        final_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.final_result);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menue, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

        switch (item.getItemId()){

            case R.id.menu_1:
                //Toast.makeText(TanavActivity2.this, "Test: Pizza Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                goToUrl("http://pizzerialibretto.com/");

                break;

            case R.id.menu_2:
                //Toast.makeText(TanavActivity2.this, "Test: Help Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                goToUrl("http://google.ca");
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    //functions for menu aka. ToolBar

    //opens up a link, after user has pressed "help!"
    public void goToUrl(String url){
        Uri uriUrl =Uri.parse(url);
        Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
        startActivity(launchBrowser);
    }


    public void selectTopping (View view){

        boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

        switch (view.getId()){

            case R.id.checkBox:
                if(checked){
                    topping.add("Onions");
                }else{
                    topping.remove("Onions");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.checkBox2:
                if(checked){
                    topping.add("Broccoli");
                }else{
                    topping.remove("Broccoli");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.checkBox3:
                if(checked){
                    topping.add("Tomatoes");
                }else{
                    topping.remove("Tomatoes");
                }

                break;
            case R.id.checkBox4:
                if(checked){
                    topping.add("Green Pepper");
                }else{
                    topping.remove("Green Pepper");
                }

                break;
            case R.id.checkBox5:
                if(checked){
                    topping.add("Ham");
                }else{
                    topping.remove("Ham");
                }

                break;
            case R.id.checkBox6:
                if(checked){
                    topping.add("Chicken");
                }else{
                    topping.remove("Chicken");
                }

                break;
            case R.id.checkBox7:
                if(checked){
                    topping.add("Pepperoni");
                }else{
                    topping.remove("Pepperoni");
                }

                break;
            case R.id.checkBox8:
                if(checked){
                    topping.add("Bacon Strips");
                }else{
                    topping.remove("Bacon Strips");
                }

                break;
            case R.id.checkBox9:
                if(checked){
                    topping.add("Chipotle Steak");
                }else{
                    topping.remove("Chipotle Steak");
                }

                break;
            case R.id.checkBox10:
                if(checked){
                    topping.add("Ground Beef");
                }else{
                    topping.remove("Ground Beef");
                }

                break;
            case R.id.checkBox11:
                if(checked){
                    topping.add("Salami");
                }else{
                    topping.remove("Salami");
                }

                break;
            case R.id.checkBox12:
                if(checked){
                    topping.add("Sausage");
                }else{
                    topping.remove("Sausage");
                }

                break;
            case R.id.checkBox13:
                if(checked){
                    topping.add("Extra Cheese");
                }else{
                    topping.remove("Extra Cheese");
                }

                break;
            case R.id.checkBox14:
                if(checked){
                    topping.add("Spinach");
                }else{
                    topping.remove("Spinach");
                }

                break;
            case R.id.checkBox15:
                if(checked){
                    topping.add("Jalapeno");
                }else{
                    topping.remove("Jalapeno");
                }

                break;
            case R.id.checkBox16:
                if(checked){
                    topping.add("Four Cheese");
                }else{
                    topping.remove("Four Cheese");
                }

                break;
            case R.id.checkBox17:
                if(checked){
                    topping.add("Pineapple");
                }else{
                    topping.remove("Pineapple");
                }

                break;
            case R.id.checkBox18:
                if(checked){
                    topping.add("Black Olives");
                }else{
                    topping.remove("Black Olives");
                }

                break;
            case R.id.checkBox19:
                if(checked){
                    topping.add("Mozzarella");
                }else{
                    topping.remove("Mozzarella");
                }

                break;
            case R.id.checkBox20:
                if(checked){
                    topping.add("Mushroom");
                }else{
                    topping.remove("Mushroom");
                }
                break;

            case R.id.checkBox21:
                if(checked){
                    topping.add("Green Olives");
                }else{
                    topping.remove("Green Olives");
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    public void finalSubmit(View view){

       String final_display = ""; //null value

        for(int i=0;i<topping.size();i++){

            String checked = topping.get(i).toString();
            final_display = final_display + checked +"\n" ;

        }
        final_text.setText("Toppings:\n" + final_display);

    }
}
```

Now how do i pass my array into new activity? I want to display what the user has selected in `firstActivity` to a new activity.

Pleaseeeee Help!

```
LogCat:
                                                          OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.06.00.05
                                                      Build Date: 01/04/16 Mon
                                                      Local Branch: 
                                                      Remote Branch: quic/LA.BR.1.2.6_rb1.7
                                                      Local Patches: NONE
                                                      Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
10-05 01:15:32.733 30647-30662/tanav.sharma I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
10-05 01:15:32.803 30647-30662/tanav.sharma D/libGLESv1: DTS_GLAPI : DTS is not allowed for Package : tanav.sharma
10-05 01:15:32.883 30647-30647/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 48 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 48 - 0, 0) or=1
10-05 01:15:32.933 30647-30647/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = android.widget.LinearLayout{5e94756 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
10-05 01:15:32.983 30647-30662/tanav.sharma V/RenderScript: 0xb79d2350 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
10-05 01:15:32.983 30647-30647/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
10-05 01:15:32.993 30647-30647/tanav.sharma I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@c2652e7 time:376047093
10-05 01:15:34.223 30647-30647/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-05 01:15:34.233 30647-30647/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
10-05 01:15:34.373 30647-30647/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-05 01:15:34.373 30647-30647/tanav.sharma I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:tanav.sharma time:376048474
10-05 01:15:34.433 30647-30647/tanav.sharma I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
10-05 01:15:34.503 30647-30647/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{7c3ae26 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
10-05 01:15:34.503 30647-30647/tanav.sharma D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : none
10-05 01:15:34.633 30647-30647/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 48 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 48 - 0, 0) or=1
10-05 01:15:34.683 30647-30647/tanav.sharma I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@afe3d81 time:376048784
10-05 01:15:34.863 30647-30647/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-05 01:15:34.883 30647-30647/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-05 01:15:34.893 30647-30647/tanav.sharma V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{7fd39ba token=android.os.BinderProxy@c2652e7 {tanav.sharma/tanav.sharma.TanavActivity2}} show : false
10-05 01:15:35.643 30647-30647/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-05 01:15:36.203 30647-30647/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-05 01:15:36.243 30647-30647/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-05 01:15:36.543 30647-30647/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-05 01:15:44.123 30647-30647/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-05 01:15:44.183 30647-30647/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-05 01:15:44.573 30647-30647/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-05 01:15:44.643 30647-30647/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-05 01:15:46.113 30647-30647/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-05 01:15:46.183 30647-30647/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-05 01:15:46.833 30647-30647/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-05 01:15:46.903 30647-30647/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-05 01:15:47.633 30647-30647/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-05 01:15:47.703 30647-30647/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-05 01:15:48.573 30647-30647/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-05 01:15:48.673 30647-30647/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-05 01:15:48.983 30647-30647/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-05 01:15:49.063 30647-30647/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-05 01:15:52.563 30647-30647/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-05 01:15:52.583 30647-30647/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-05 01:15:52.673 30647-30647/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-05 01:15:52.783 30647-30647/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-05 01:16:26.923 31667-31667/tanav.sharma W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/tanav.sharma-1/lib/arm

                                                      [ 10-05 01:16:26.933 31667:31667 W/         ]
                                                      Unable to open '/system/framework/qcom.fmradio.jar': No such file or directory
10-05 01:16:26.933 31667-31667/tanav.sharma W/art: Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/qcom.fmradio.jar': I/O Error
10-05 01:16:28.373 31667-31667/tanav.sharma W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/tanav.sharma-1/lib/arm
10-05 01:16:28.563 31667-31667/tanav.sharma W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
10-05 01:16:29.033 31667-31667/tanav.sharma D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : none
10-05 01:16:29.033 31667-31667/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{b176dce I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
10-05 01:16:29.043 31667-31873/tanav.sharma D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
10-05 01:16:29.073 31667-31873/tanav.sharma I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: Nondeterministic_AU_msm8916_32_LA.BR.1.2.6_RB1__release_AU (Ia10634f51b)
                                                          OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.06.00.05
                                                          Build Date: 01/04/16 Mon
                                                          Local Branch: 
                                                          Remote Branch: quic/LA.BR.1.2.6_rb1.7
                                                          Local Patches: NONE
                                                          Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
10-05 01:16:29.083 31667-31873/tanav.sharma I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
10-05 01:16:29.103 31667-31873/tanav.sharma D/libGLESv1: DTS_GLAPI : DTS is not allowed for Package : tanav.sharma
10-05 01:16:29.203 31667-31667/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 48 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 48 - 0, 0) or=1
10-05 01:16:29.323 31667-31667/tanav.sharma I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@c6012c9 time:376103429
10-05 01:16:33.873 31667-31667/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-05 01:16:33.903 31667-31667/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-05 01:16:33.903 31667-31667/tanav.sharma I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:tanav.sharma time:376108005
10-05 01:16:33.973 31667-31667/tanav.sharma I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
10-05 01:16:34.393 31667-31667/tanav.sharma D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : none
10-05 01:16:34.393 31667-31667/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{6a44f19 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
10-05 01:16:34.533 31667-31667/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 48 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 48 - 0, 0) or=1
10-05 01:16:34.603 31667-31667/tanav.sharma I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@6f7ce60 time:376108700
10-05 01:16:34.793 31667-31667/tanav.sharma V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{8b50978 token=android.os.BinderProxy@c6012c9 {tanav.sharma/tanav.sharma.TanavActivity}} show : false
10-05 01:16:36.963 31667-31667/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-05 01:16:37.043 31667-31667/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-05 01:16:37.043 31667-31667/tanav.sharma I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:tanav.sharma time:376111146
10-05 01:16:37.103 31667-31667/tanav.sharma I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
10-05 01:16:37.183 31667-31667/tanav.sharma D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : none
10-05 01:16:37.183 31667-31667/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{3449061 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
10-05 01:16:37.293 31667-31667/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 48 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 48 - 0, 0) or=1
10-05 01:16:37.343 31667-31667/tanav.sharma I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@b26a7c8 time:376111449
10-05 01:16:37.573 31667-31667/tanav.sharma V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{e07ffc5 token=android.os.BinderProxy@6f7ce60 {tanav.sharma/tanav.sharma.TanavActivity2}} show : false
10-05 01:16:39.213 31667-31667/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-05 01:16:39.283 31667-31667/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-05 01:16:40.873 31667-31667/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-05 01:16:41.003 31667-31667/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-05 01:16:44.763 31667-31667/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-05 01:16:44.893 31667-31667/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-05 01:16:44.913 31667-31667/tanav.sharma I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:tanav.sharma time:376119011
10-05 01:16:45.013 31667-31667/tanav.sharma D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
10-05 01:16:45.013 31667-31667/tanav.sharma E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                              Process: tanav.sharma, PID: 31667
                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tanav.sharma/tanav.sharma.TanavActivityOrder}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.String[]
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3319)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7331)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                               Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.String[]
                                                                  at tanav.sharma.TanavActivityOrder.onCreate(TanavActivityOrder.java:27)
                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7331) 
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
10-05 01:16:52.573 31667-31667/tanav.sharma I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 31667 SIG: 9
10-05 01:16:52.773 32582-32582/tanav.sharma W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/tanav.sharma-1/lib/arm
10-05 01:16:52.893 32582-32582/tanav.sharma W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/tanav.sharma-1/lib/arm
10-05 01:16:53.083 32582-32582/tanav.sharma W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
10-05 01:16:53.313 32582-32582/tanav.sharma I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
10-05 01:16:53.713 32582-32582/tanav.sharma D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : none
10-05 01:16:53.723 32582-32582/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{1a10d3d I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
10-05 01:16:53.723 32582-32623/tanav.sharma D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
10-05 01:16:53.783 32582-32623/tanav.sharma I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: Nondeterministic_AU_msm8916_32_LA.BR.1.2.6_RB1__release_AU (Ia10634f51b)
                                                          OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.06.00.05
                                                          Build Date: 01/04/16 Mon
                                                          Local Branch: 
                                                          Remote Branch: quic/LA.BR.1.2.6_rb1.7


       Local Patches: NONE
                                                          Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
10-05 01:16:53.783 32582-32623/tanav.sharma I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
10-05 01:16:53.853 32582-32623/tanav.sharma D/libGLESv1: DTS_GLAPI : DTS is not allowed for Package : tanav.sharma
10-05 01:16:53.933 32582-32582/tanav.sharma D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 48 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 48 - 0, 0) or=1
10-05 01:16:53.983 32582-32582/tanav.sharma I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@f3dde94 time:376128081
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [passing Entire ArrayList<String> from one activity to other in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029958/passing-entire-arrayliststring-from-one-activity-to-other-in-android)

Comment: intent.putStringArrayListExtra("key",arraylist);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing arraylist of objects between activities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790499/passing-arraylist-of-objects-between-activities)

Comment: @user5425093 check my answer

Comment: That logcat has no errors in it

Comment: i placed the wrong logcat, can you please check again. I apologize for placing the wrong one earlier

Comment: @user5425093 plz check my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

To pass `ArrayList` to another Activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(TanavActivityAd1.this,TanavActivityOrder.class);
i.putExtra("Choice", topping);
startActivity(i);
```

get `Arraylist` in another Activity:

```
ArrayList<String> toppings = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Choice");


for(int i=0;i<toppings.size();i++) {
    String s[]= toppings.get(i);
    for(int iv=0;iv<s.length;iv++)
    Log.i("..............:",""+s[iv]);
}
```

Comment: in my second activity.. do i place the code in my onCreate method?

Comment: yes .you put this code in oncreate method @user5425093

Comment: Okay, when i run the code on my app, it crashes my app. I put the code that passes the array in my submit button. Was that the right place to put it?

Comment: you take checkbox in xml layout @user5425093

Comment: @user5425093 plz post your logcat

Comment: i added the the catlog, please check

Comment: Why do you have a String array inside of a list?

Comment: @DaminiMehra i tried your updated code, and it give me the following error: 

incompatible types: String cannot be converted to string[]

Comment: @DaminiMehra second activity

Comment: @user5425093 please put debug at ArrayList<String> toppings = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Choice"); and check you get data here

Comment: it doesnt even let me compile the program. it says there is something wrong with "String s[] = toppings.get(i);" gives me the above error..

Comment: @user5425093 plz comment this code for(int i=0;i<toppings.size();i++) {
    String s[]= toppings.get(i);
    for(int iv=0;iv<s.length;iv++)
    Log.i("..............:",""+s[iv]);
}  and check

Comment: @user5425093 print log for arraylist

Comment: i ran the debugger, but it did not save the values.. how do i print the log for array list?

Comment: @user5425093   Log.i("arlist"toppings.toString()); try this .let me know

Comment: nope, gave me error: `)` expected ... illegal start of expression .... `;` expected. :(

Comment: check this:  Log.i("arlist",toppings.toString());

Comment: okay nvm i fixed it.. it works and it passes the variable. when i put a breakpoint at `Log.i("arlist",toppings.toString());` it tells me the size of the array is 2. and it makes sense, because I selected two toppings before clicking submit

Comment: @user5425093 ok now take your data from arraylist and this ans help to you then accept the answer

Comment: @DaminiMehra u are totally awesome! thanks for everything! but how to display it? and can you explain to me what `Log.i("arlist",toppings.toString());` does. Thank you!

Comment: @user5425093  for(int i=0;i<toppings.size();i++){

            String checked = toppings.get(i).toString();
            Log.i("chk",checked)

        }

Comment: it doesnt work the prinitng. I get no errors, and it everything works perfectly fine, but it doesnt print the list.  I really do appreciate your help thoe, and i appreciate all the time you put in this to help me out.

Comment: @user5425093 check this link : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arraylist_get.htm

Answer (score 0):

From Activity A-->B

```
Intent intent=new Intent(A.this,B.class);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("LIST","your array list");
```

IN activity B get List by following way..

```
ArrayList<String>list=getIntent.getStringArrayListExtra("LIST")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this,

```
Intent i = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
i.putStringArrayListExtra("key", stringArrayList);
startActivity(i);
```

on receiving activity (in this case B) you can receive list like below

```
ArrayList<String> list = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("key")
```

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a school assignment I won't put any code but you can pass it through an intent extra. You'll create an intent, put your topping array list on the intent with a tag using

`intent.putExtra(tag, topping)`

and then call

`startActivity(intent)`.

In the target actiivity of the intent you can call

`getIntent().getSerializable(tag)`

to return a list with the toppings contents. OK I lied, I put some code, good luck!